# How to create a React Link to make API call through click handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

quick question. Does anyone know how to construct a call to a click/event handler for the react-router `<Link>` component. If I have this API data return in `searchData` and mapping over the values how do you call an event Handler and pass `{key}` and `{v}` to the click handler?

`` <Link to={`${key}/${v}`}><li>{v}</li></Link>)) ``

Answer (score 0):

When defined without a specific `component` prop, the `<Link>` component in React Router defaults as a common anchor: `<a>`. You can pass any prop to this component by defining the props on the `<Link>` component. You can pass the `key` and `v` variables in the function you define on the `onClick` prop.

For example:

```js
<Link to={`${key}/${v}`} onClick={e => onClickHandler(e, key, v)}>
  <li>{v}</li>
</Link>
```

Here is a link to the `<Link>` component definition to see how it works:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js